# Remix IDE won't run my file and give no compilation errors

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, remix

As in the title, My file (that is a sample file) gives no compilation errors and does not run. It's called "StandardToken.Sol".

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your contracts end with ".sol" not ".Sol" or any other permutation of the letters.